# Is there a way to remove the pause button from the custom camera view in Android?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am building an Android app that uses the phone's camera feature. I know there is a way to build a custom camera view. Instead, I am choosing to use the camera app via an intent and not build my own camera view. I want to disable/make disappear the pause button while taking a video and have just the stop button. I looked up the Camera API Guide at www.developer.android.com but it doesn't talk about how I could do this. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doesn't think that this is possible. Using Intents is just a way to tell Android "hey, I'd like to take a video (photo, see MapView, etc). Can you do it for me?". It may trigger one or MORE Apps listening to that Intent, depending on what apps the user has Installed. Usually you can only choose very basic options via Intents, i.e. take video/picture or tell the MapView at which Position it should show up. These options usually also appear inside the App during normal use. I never see a "CustomCamera-App" that hasn't a pause Button, or where one is able to deactivate it inside the menu. Therefore the chances that it is possible to set that special option tends to zero.